# unpivot columns into two new columns in Stream Analytics

Tags: sql, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have a stream from IoT Hub like:

```
{
    "store_id": "111",
    "data": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2018-04-06T11:46:11.842305",
            "book_id": "001",
            "author_id": "101"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2018-04-06T11:46:11.842306",
            "book_id": "002",
            "author_id": "102"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2018-04-06T11:46:11.842307",
            "book_id": "003",
            "author_id": "103"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to pass this stream in a SQL DB like this:

```
id    id_type     timestamp 
001   book_id     2018-04-06T11:46:11.842305  
101   author_id   2018-04-06T11:46:11.842305 
002   book_id     2018-04-06T11:46:11.842306 
102   author_id   2018-04-06T11:46:11.842306 
003   book_id     2018-04-06T11:46:11.842307 
103   author_id   2018-04-06T11:46:11.842307
```

is there any way to use `cross apply` or other way to create two new columns form multi json element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a static pivot (you know in advance the list of fields and you can hardcode their value), then you get there with something like this:

```
WITH Unfolding AS (
    SELECT
        d.ArrayValue.*
    FROM input i
    CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(i.data) d
),
Books AS (
    SELECT
        timestamp,
        book_id as id,
        'book' as id_type
    FROM Unfolding
),
Authors AS (
    SELECT
        timestamp,
        author_id as id,
        'author' as id_type
    FROM Unfolding
),
AllRecords AS (
    SELECT timestamp, id, id_type FROM Books
    UNION
    SELECT timestamp, id, id_type FROM Authors
)
SELECT
    *
INTO output
FROM AllRecords
```

You create one [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/with-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) per entities to extract and UNION them all at the end.

If you have dynamic values, you will need to use a [JavaScript UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions). I don't have a code sample sadly. It should be straightforward (but a bit painful).